# Remove object property inside ReactJs element - using spread syntax

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm triyng to remove an object property using spread syntax rendering a React component. I wonder if there is a way to achieve without adding to much extra code. I'm using {reset,...inputName}

I have a custom hook (useField) for every input in my form. useField also has a reset function for my reset button. But I want to remove the reset property only for the inputs element.

**custom hook useField**

```
export const useField = (type) => {

  const [value, setValue] = useState('')

  const onChange = (event) => {
    setValue(event.target.value)
  }

  const reset = () => {
    setValue('')
  }

  return {
    type,
    value,
    onChange,
    reset
  }
}
```

**react form**

```
const MyForm = (props) => {

  const content = useField('text')
  const author = useField('text')
  const info = useField('text')
 
  const handleClick = () => {
    content.reset()
    author.reset()
    info.reset()
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <h2>create a new anecdote</h2>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <div>
          content
          <input {reset,...content} />
        </div>
        <div>
          author
          <input {reset,...author} />
        </div>
        <div>
          url for more info
          <input {reset,...info} />
        </div>
        <button>create</button>
        <input type="reset" value='reset' onClick={handleClick} />
      </form>
    </div>
  )

}
```

Comment: You can't delete properties in a spread like that but you can make a function that does it and spread the result for less clutter?

Comment: Suppose we have an object like so: `const obj = {'a': 10, 'b': 20, 'c': 30, 'd': 40};` and we need to 'remove' prop `'a'` using `...` spread - it can be done like this: `const {a, ...rest} = obj; const newObj = {...rest};`. Now, `newObj` will not have the prop `a`. If you replace `const` with `let`, then instead of `newObj`, you can say `obj` itself. So, effectively, `'a'` is removed from `obj`.

Comment: Please trying changing: `const content = useField('text')` to `const {reset: resetContent, ...content} = useField('text')`. I am hoping that `reset` will no longer be within `content`. Then, you may use `resetContent` in your `handleClick` while using `content` for JSX.

Comment: @jsN00b great solution, thanks! It's exactly what i was looking for, avoid to lose much of the benefit provided by custom hooks and spread syntax!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For future reference, what may work for OP are changes similar to below:

```
  const { reset: resetContent, ...content} = useField('text')
  const { reset: resetAuthor, ...author} = useField('text')
  const { rest: resetInfo, ...info} = useField('text')
 
  const handleClick = () => {
    resetContent();
    resetAuthor();
    resetInfo();
  };
.
.
.
  <div>
   content
   <input {...content} />
  </div>
.
.
.
```

Explanation

- the object returned from `useField` is destructured
- the `reset` prop is separated and renamed as `resetContent` (or `resetAuthor`, `resetInfo`, as required)
- the rest of the props go into the `content` variable (or `author`, `info` variables, as required)
- when rendering in the JSX, the `content` is used

Thus, effectively the `reset` prop from `useField` was `'removed'` (technically, it was just separated, though) in the new `content` object.